# How to check existance and nil in single line for variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

```
 def import_update   
    require 'csv'
    file = params[:file]
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

@prod = Spree::Product.find(row["id"])
@var = Spree::Variant.find_by(product_id: @prod.id)
Spree::Product.where(:id => row["id"]).update_all(:name => row["name"] if !row[name].nil?.present?, :meta_description => row["meta_description"], :shipping_category_id => row["shipping_category_id"], :description => row["description"], :meta_keywords => row["meta_keywords"], :tax_category_id => row["tax_category_id"], :available_on => row["available_on"], :deleted_at => row["deleted_at"], :promotionable => row["promotionable"], :meta_title => row["meta_title"], :featured => row["featured"], :supplier_id => row["supplier_id"])   
             end   
 end
```

I want check that row is present or not. if it is present then it updated when it is not null and condition is in single line because I want to apply this for all variable in updation statement.I wrote code above but showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
params = ["name","meta_description","shipping_category_id","description","meta_keywords","tax_category_id","available_on","deleted_at","promotionable","meta_title","featured","supplier_id"
hash = {}

params.each do |param|
  if row[param]
    hash[param] = row[param]
  end
end
Spree::Product.where(:id => row["id"]).update_attributes(hash)
```

This will let you keep your code dry.

EDIT:

What are these lines supposed to do?:

```
@prod = Spree::Product.find(row["id"])
@var = Spree::Variant.find_by(product_id: @prod.id)
```

I presume you don't have several entries with one ID. And your not using the objects that you retrieved in those two lines, so simply write the method like this:

```
def import_update   
    require 'csv'
    file = params[:file]
  params = ["name","meta_description","shipping_category_id","description","meta_keywords","tax_category_id","available_on","deleted_at","promotionable","meta_title","featured","supplier_id"]
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
       hash = {} 
       params.each do |param|
         if row[param]
           hash[param] = row[param]
         end
       end
       Spree::Product.find(row["id"]).update_all(hash)
    end  
 end
```

Comment: getting error "undefined method `update_all' " @Kkulikovskis

Comment: but works with Spree::Product.find(row["id"]).update_attributes(hash)